# Using request attribute object properties dynamically

Tags: jsp, jstl

I am using Spring MVC application and I have a JSP with following code.

```html
<c:choose>
            <c:when test="${type eq 'school'}">
            <h1 class="title">${schoolVO.name}</h1>
            </c:when>

            <c:when test="${type eq 'college'}">
            <h1 class="title">${collegeVO.name}</h1>

            </c:when>

            <c:when test="${type eq 'tution'}">
             <h1 class="title">${tutionVO.name}</h1>
            </c:when>
            ...
            ..
            ..
            Many other types...

</c:choose>
```

This jsp is called when there is a method in controller which depend on the `type` 
set the model attribute .

If the type is `school` , it puts

```
modelMap.addAttribute("schoolVO", school);
```

if college  then

```
modelMap.addAttribute("collegeVO", college);
```

Similarly others..

Now i want to remove this `<c:when>` conditions in `jsp`.

Now depending upon the type I want to add one model attribute and put either 
`schoolVO` or `collgeVO` like

```
modelMap.addAttribute("typeVO", "schoolVO");
```

So that I did not need to use if `<c:when>` conditions in `jsp` .
And I want to use something like

```
${{typeVO}.name}
```

But this gives me error

```
 contains invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException: Error Parsing:
```

How i can achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

P.S. I could not get the proper title for my question. Please change it if there is something appropriate i can put.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can complicate yourself having lots of different attributes set in the request. AFAIK, it would be better to have a single attribute that handles the name you want to print:

```
modelMap.addAttribute("institutionName", school.getName());
//or
modelMap.addAttribute("institutionName", college.getName());
```

That contains the title you will print, then in your JSP you don't have use any validation, just write

```html
<h1 class="title">${institutionName}</h1>
```

Comment: Actually this part of my code is the header of the jsp and in the differnet file. The rest of the body is different for each type.

Comment: If i want to view College , the remaining body contains code using college object and similarly for others.

Comment: If that's your problem (still really odd) then you can use BkSantiago's answer.

Comment: Hey missed double quotes `modelMap.addAttribute("typeVO", "schoolVO");`  I think his answer will not work . I am sorry for my mistake

Comment: Did you understand my problem or you need any clarification?

Comment: @vikiiii I can only tell that your `school` and `college` (and other similar variables) should extend from a class that contains the name and other common attributes you want/need to use, save this as a request attribute and use it to display the similar data for all these entities, and then using your validations in your code.

Comment: @vikiiii by the way I understood what you want to do, but that's impossible, you can't dynamically get the name of the request attribute and then get it's properties (that would be like doing reflection for the reflection), I guess the better approach will be the one stated in my last comment.

Answer (score 0):

If All of them have a field called `name` then you can just do `${typeVO.name}`